# error when running az appconfig from command line

Tags: azure, azure-app-configuration

I am getting the following error when running az appconfig

> az appconfig kv export: error: the following arguments are required:
>   --destination/-d

```
az appconfig kv export -f bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\azureappconfig.json --format json --separator : --connection-string Endpoint=https://tvtestappconfig.azconfig.io;Id=fwef34rw432r32f43;Secret=123412341234123412344=
```

> Extensions: appconfig                          0.5.0

I was following instruction in this link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/integrate-ci-cd-pipeline

Comment: From that error, you lack `--destination {appconfig, appservice, file} `, see these example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/appconfig/appconfig/kv?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-appconfig-az-appconfig-kv-export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to export to a file. In that case you need to pass **-d file** (short for **--destination file**).

`az appconfig kv export --destination file -f bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\azureappconfig.json --format json --separator : --connection-string {ConnectionString}`